# What is the quickest way to measure distance betwen 2 nodes in NEO4j

Tags: neo4j

I have the (day) nodes with (:NEXT) relationship so

> (year {year:2014})-
>      [:HAS_MONTH]->(month {month:1})-
>      [:HAS_DAY]->(day {day:1})-
>           [:NEXT]->(day {day:2})

and so on.

What is the quickest way to measure distance between 2 nodes if let's say I wanted to measure from Year 2020 -> Month 12 -> Day 31 back to 1/1/2014?

I have attempted to use [:NEXT*] however that just times out, lowering that down to [:NEXT*0..100] appear to execute (though not very fast)

Comment: use labels like `:Year` with an index on `:Year(year)` and `shortestPath((day1)-[:NEXT*]->(day2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe posting the query you used could help us optimize it, also it shows you try something and how you tried it.

Normally this kind of query should run very fast if you find a way to match the start and end nodes efficiently.

In your current model, the year nodes are unique and should then use the unique constraint schema index, from there you can find the nodes you want efficiently.

```
MATCH (y:Year {year:2020})
MATCH (y)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(month {month:12})-[:HAS_DAY]->(day {day:31})
WITH day
MATCH (y2:Year {year:2014})
MATCH (y2)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(month2 {month:1})-[:HAS_DAY]->(day2 {day:1})
MATCH p=(day2)-[:NEXT*]->(day)
RETURN length(p)
```

However, there are a few points that can help with your situation and optimize the current query:

- Use a timestamp indexed property on day nodes for a really fast direct access
- Use a `LAST` relationship between the year and the December node of the year, same for `FIRST` and January and same for days in each month
- Make sure to use labels and indexes/constraints on your year, month and day nodes

Also, you may want to look at the GraphAware TimeTree Neo4j plugin : https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, your query if I run it, comparing 2 days together takes about 100ms to respond back. If I wish to compare all dates back (day2)-[:NEXT*]->(alldays), that's when things slow down considerably.

Also I looked at the link, that looks to be a great plugin, it's limited to Java and REST calls. Maybe I'm missing on how I can apply that into my workflow that uses Cypher? I didn't see any examples there.

Comment: please post the query you use and also a dump of your schema

Comment: Right now my schema is just Year -> Month -> Day  and that's it. I am trying to figure out a best possible use of time stamping future events so that I can quickly items based on date/time ranges at least in UTC and put some more advanced logic of setting up WHERE clause outside of Cypher that would translate users's timezone back to UTC for example.

I'd like to have resolution as low as possible like down to 1 minute.

Comment: I was meaning your index schema, type  :schema   in the browser and post the result. The feature for getting events between a time range are fully supported by the GraphAware TimeTree module.

Comment: SHELL:schema
No indexes
No constraints

Comment: So GraphAware TimeTree Module, looks to only be making it's functions available through REST api calls and Java plugins which can be made to further extend REST api. 

So if I wanted to have more complex queries like show me all Users who signed up between these 2 days who have not yet logged on but use an iPhone. How would that work with GraphAware TimeTree module in terms of running the queries?

Comment: You will need to do separate requests when using TimeTree. but your query is a piece of cake for Neo4j and Cypher, you should just add schema indexes on your time nodes as I said in my answer.